Sass bundle with Symfony : import issue
I am using the Sass bundle (https://symfony.com/bundles/SassBundle/current/index.html) for Symfony.
I have a file assets/styles/front/main/contenus.scss:
@import "../variables.scss";

.test { 
  color: $c-primary; 
}

.video {
  height: 240px;
}

I include it in my rechercher.html.twig view like this:
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('styles/front/main/contenus.scss') }}">
{% endblock %}

The code related to the .video class is interpreted correctly, but I get a console error in the browser stating that the variables.scss file is "not found":

GET https://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/styles/front/variables net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

However, the _variables.scss file is indeed present in /assets/styles/front/.
How can I import it?

According to the docs you have to point your {{ asset() }} to the .scss file, not the css file. So it would be {{ asset('assets/styles/front/main/contenus.scss') }}

@JulianKoster Sorry, that's what i do, i've edited my question.
I point to contenu.scss and i get the error :)

What is the output of php bin/console sass:build?
And did you exclude scss from AssetMapper?

Try it withouth the extension, so just @import "../variables";
And if You have the contenus.css file too, check if the variable file's content is in there or not.
